# The Sieve of Eratosthenes in C using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, stdio, sieve-of-eratosthenes, math.h

I'ma beginner in C and I have to convert The Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm into C code.  This is the algorithm given: 
*START
Initialize the array is_prime so that all the values of the
elements will be TRUE.
set the value of is_prime[1] to be FALSE (since 1 is NOT prime.)
For I=2 until sqrt(N) execute:
set all the multiples of I to FALSE, starting with I*I
until N.
Print all the indexes of is_prime that hold the value TRUE.
END*

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>        
#include <math.h>

#define N 300             

void displayPrime (bool checkPrime);         
bool checkPrime (int num);

main()                    
{
     bool is_prime[N+1];         

     displayPrime(is_prime);

     getchar();      
}

void displayPrime (bool check)          
{
     int I;

     for(I=1; I<N; I++)
     {
              checkPrime(is_prime[I]);
              if(is_prime[I]==TRUE)
              {
                      printf("%d\n", I);
              }
              else if(is_prime[I]==FALSE)
              {
                      printf("");
              }
     }
}

bool checkPrime (int num)
{
     int num;

     is_prime[1]=FALSE;
     for(I=2; I<=sqrt(N); I++)
     {
              for(num=I; num<=N/num; num=num*I)
              {
                      is_prime[num]=FALSE;    
              }         
              return(is_prime[I]);
     }

}
```

The program does not compile, and I'm wondering what is wrong with the program.  Thank you

Comment: If the program does not compile: What is the error message?

Comment: What does the compiler say?  Doesn't it point to a specific line?  Ask the compiler to emit warnings, it'll give you more clues.

Comment: since when you have bool in C ?(not c++)
A define?

Comment: your naming is *tres tres terrible*. The errors are [here](http://ideone.com/pAtzje).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not looking into the algorithm. This is the working code (Using visual studio):

```
#include <stdio.h>        
#include <math.h>

#define N 300             

void displayPrime (bool checkPrime);         
bool checkPrime (int num);
bool is_prime[N+1];


void displayPrime (bool check)          
{
     int I;

     for(I=1; I<N; I++)
     {
              checkPrime(is_prime[I]);
              if(is_prime[I]==true)
              {
                      printf("%d\n", I);
              }
              else if(is_prime[I]==false)
              {
                      printf("");
              }
     }
}

bool checkPrime (int num)
{
     int I;
     is_prime[1]=false;
     for(I=2; I*I<=N; I++)
     {
              for(num=I; num<=N/num; num=num*I)
              {
                      is_prime[num]=false;    
              }         
              return(is_prime[I]);
     }

}

void main()                    
{

     displayPrime(is_prime);

     getchar();      
}
```

I have changed these things:

1. You cannot declare a variable twice.
2. Every variable can be used within scope `{}`
3. A function called should be declared before you call.
4. `TRUE` should be `true` and `FALSE` should be `false`.
5. use return type in main function.

Anyway `Sieve` has a lot of good implementation. Try them out.

Comment: `checkPrime` is `boolean` type variable declared as `bool`

Comment: no, it is a function. oh, wait, it *is* a bool var. **NO**, it is a function.... Wait, what is it??? *I don't know!!*

Comment: See this is both... There is a variable as well as a function in same name... That is not a problem from compiler side... This will also do the same `void displayPrime (bool );` Because in forward declaration variable name is not important only the important thing is function name and data type.

Comment: No!!! And it is *good and sound practice*, why exactly?? Compiler's fine with it, what about people who have to read this *code*?

Comment: `practice` is all for men... compiler doesn't have any problem. you can declare what you like.